# Getting data from MPU9250, cant get an stable reading

Tags: pi-3b+

I am trying to retrieve data from the MPU9250 and can get raw data, the issue occurs whenever I am trying to use it, its all over the place, one reading 65 and the next one is 255 and then goes down to 5.

I decided to get a simple median number but for some odd reason now I get only 1, do not know if I have to calibrate the MPU first or something, and honestly I do not want to get into quaternion stuff yet, baby steps first.

Here is my code:

```
#include <../stdint.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "../pigpio.h"       // PIGPIO.h , c++ library for GPIO control on Raspberry pi 3 model B+
#include "Register_Map.h"    // Mapa de Registros MPU9250
//#include "Ejes.h"    Antiguo

/*   Leer datos del sensor usando I2C
*  Addres of MPU-9250 :0x68
*/

int GyroX()
{
   int a,b,c,d = 0;
   int mediaX;

//i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); enable i2c comms, bus is 1, the addres of the sensor is 0x68
//i2cOpen(Bus seleccionado, Direccion sensor, Flag debe ser 0) 

 int sensor;
 sensor=i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); // handler its a variable, in this case sensor, NEVER INSIDE A LOOP!!!!!

 a = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x44);
 b = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x44);
 c = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x44);
 d = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x44);

 mediaX = (a+b+c+d)/4;

 return mediaX;
}

 int GyroY()
 {
 int a,b,c,d;
 int mediaY;

 //i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); enable i2c comms, bus is 1, the addres of the sensor is 0x68
//i2cOpen(Bus seleccionado, Direccion sensor, Flag debe ser 0) 

 int sensor;
 sensor=i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); // handler its a variable, in this case sensor, NEVER INSIDE A LOOP!!!!!

 a = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x46);
 b = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x46);
 c = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x46);
 d = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x46);

 mediaY = (a+b+c+d)/4;

 return mediaY;
}

int GyroZ()
{
int a,b,c,d;
int mediaZ;

//i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); enable i2c comms, bus is 1, the addres of the sensor is 0x68
//i2cOpen(Bus seleccionado, Direccion sensor, Flag debe ser 0) 

 int sensor;
 sensor=i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); // handler its a variable, in this case sensor, NEVER INSIDE A LOOP!!!!!

 a = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x48);
 b = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x48);
 c = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x48);
 d = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x48);

 mediaZ = (a+b+c+d)/4;

 return mediaZ;
}

int AccelerometroX()
{
int a,b,c,d;
int media;

//i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); enable i2c comms, bus is 1, the addres of the sensor is 0x68
//i2cOpen(Bus seleccionado, Direccion sensor, Flag debe ser 0) 

 int sensor;
 sensor=i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); // handler its a variable, in this case sensor, NEVER INSIDE A LOOP!!!!!

 a = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x3C);
 b = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x3C);
 c = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x3C);
 d = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x3C);

 media = (a+b+c+d)/4;

 return media;
 }

 int AccelerometroY()
{
int a,b,c,d;
int media;

//i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); enable i2c comms, bus is 1, the addres of the sensor is 0x68
//i2cOpen(Bus seleccionado, Direccion sensor, Flag debe ser 0) 

 int sensor;
 sensor=i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); // handler its a variable, in this case sensor, NEVER INSIDE A LOOP!!!!!

 a = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x3E);
 b = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x3E);
 c = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x3E);
 d = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x3E);

 media = (a+b+c+d)/4;

 return media;
 }

int AccelerometroZ()
{
int a,b,c,d;
int media;

//i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); enable i2c comms, bus is 1, the addres of the sensor is 0x68
//i2cOpen(Bus seleccionado, Direccion sensor, Flag debe ser 0) 

 int sensor;
 sensor=i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); // handler its a variable, in this case sensor, NEVER INSIDE A LOOP!!!!!

 a = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x40);
 b = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x40);
 c = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x40);
 d = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x40);

 media = (a+b+c+d)/4;

 return media;
}

void MostrarData()
{
//i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); enable i2c comms, bus is 1, the addres of the sensor is 0x68
//i2cOpen(Bus seleccionado, Direccion sensor, Flag debe ser 0) 

 int sensor;
 sensor=i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); // handler its a variable, in this case sensor, NEVER INSIDE A LOOP!!!!!

for (;;)
{
   // Reading Gyroscope data
   std::cout << "Gyro 'X': " << GyroX << "   ";
   std::cout << "Gyro 'Y': " << GyroY << "   ";
   std::cout << "Gyro 'Z': " << GyroZ << "   ";
   std::cout << "Temperatura: " << i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x42) << std::endl;
   //Reading Accelerometer Data
   std::cout << "Accele 'X': " << AccelerometroX << "   ";
   std::cout << "Accele 'Y': " << AccelerometroY << "   ";
   std::cout << "Accele 'Z': " << AccelerometroZ << "   " << std::endl;

 }

 gpioTerminate();

}


int main(void) {


gpioInitialise();      // inicializa la libreria
if (gpioInitialise() <=0)  // check if library its working
   {  
      std::cout << "gpio not initialise";
      return 0;
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "gpio working fine" << std::endl << std::endl;
   } 

MostrarData();

return 0;
}
```

I do get raw data from the sensor but I simply cannot analyze properly.
Any help is welcome!

---

EDIT: i did some research about converting 8 bits into 16 bits value, and found they must appeand together in order to be used properly, so i came out with something like this:

Code:

```
int8_t sensor_data_High[5];
int8_t sensor_data_Low[5];
int16_t compuesto[5];
int media;
int sensor;

sensor=i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); 

 sensor_data_High[1] = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x47);
 sensor_data_High[2] = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x47);
 sensor_data_High[3] = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x47);
 sensor_data_High[4] = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x47);

 sensor_data_Low[1] = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x48);
 sensor_data_Low[2] = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x48);
 sensor_data_Low[3] = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x48);
 sensor_data_Low[4] = i2cReadByteData(sensor,0x48);

 compuesto[1] = sensor_data_High[1] << 8 | (sensor_data_Low[1] & 0xFF); 
 compuesto[2] = sensor_data_High[2] << 8 | (sensor_data_Low[2] & 0xFF); 
 compuesto[3] = sensor_data_High[3] << 8 | (sensor_data_Low[3] & 0xFF); 
 compuesto[4] = sensor_data_High[4] << 8 | (sensor_data_Low[4] & 0xFF); 

 i2cClose(sensor);

 return media = (compuesto[1] + compuesto[2] + compuesto[3] + compuesto[4]) / 4;
```

im not sure if this is the best way to analyce and IMU and get rid of the noice associated with it, but at least now im getting more stable reading.

- can someone tell me if this is the best way to use it?
- I am making a mistake trying to append the 16 bit var this way??
- or maybe i need to calibrate the IMU first.
  Thanks

This is the output from the program all together:

```
Gyro 'X': -18   Gyro 'Y': 0   Gyro 'Z': 142   
Temperatura: 2704
Accele 'X': 16155   Accele 'Y': -2985   Accele 'Z': -1490   


Gyro 'X': -20   Gyro 'Y': 174   Gyro 'Z': 116   
Temperatura: 2804
Accele 'X': 16140   Accele 'Y': -3190   Accele 'Z': -1424   


Gyro 'X': 100   Gyro 'Y': 9   Gyro 'Z': 120   
Temperatura: 2664
Accele 'X': 16166   Accele 'Y': -3240   Accele 'Z': -1330   


Gyro 'X': 36   Gyro 'Y': -32   Gyro 'Z': 154   
Temperatura: 2792
Accele 'X': 16190   Accele 'Y': -3120   Accele 'Z': -1525   


Gyro 'X': -19   Gyro 'Y': 25   Gyro 'Z': 129   
Temperatura: 2692
Accele 'X': 16078   Accele 'Y': -3130   Accele 'Z': -1437   


Gyro 'X': 174   Gyro 'Y': -175   Gyro 'Z': 89   
Temperatura: 2784
Accele 'X': 16116   Accele 'Y': -3083   Accele 'Z': -1432   


Gyro 'X': -31   Gyro 'Y': -166   Gyro 'Z': 139   
Temperatura: 2712
Accele 'X': 16164   Accele 'Y': -3308   Accele 'Z': -1368   


Gyro 'X': -11   Gyro 'Y': 123   Gyro 'Z': 102   
Temperatura: 2784
Accele 'X': 16162   Accele 'Y': -3097   Accele 'Z': -1362   


Gyro 'X': -9   Gyro 'Y': 75   Gyro 'Z': 155   
Temperatura: 2656
Accele 'X': 16154   Accele 'Y': -3122   Accele 'Z': -1411   


Gyro 'X': -189   Gyro 'Y': -64   Gyro 'Z': 135   
Temperatura: 2808
Accele 'X': 16157   Accele 'Y': -2916   Accele 'Z': -1404
```

---

EDIT 2: I took the idea from Nomad Maker and cleaned my code, its not exacly 100% like he told me but i feel its kinda close, also found code about quaternion and checking the kalman filter, but i want to know wich one is best?

code:

```
int GyroY()
{
  //      GYRO_YOUT_H      0x45     the definition of this variables
  //      GYRO_YOUT_L      0x46     are inside Register_Map.h
 int8_t sensor_data_High[5];
 int8_t sensor_data_Low[5];
 int16_t compuesto[5];
 int media;
 int sensor;

 sensor=i2cOpen(1,0x68,0); 
 for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
 {
    sensor_data_High[i] = i2cReadByteData(sensor,GYRO_YOUT_H);
    sensor_data_Low[i] = i2cReadByteData(sensor,GYRO_YOUT_L);
    compuesto[i] = sensor_data_High[i] << 8 | (sensor_data_Low[i] & 0xFF);
  }
  i2cClose(sensor);

  return media = (compuesto[1] + compuesto[2] + compuesto[3] + compuesto[4]) / 4;
}
```

Comment: (a+b+c+d)/4 is an odd calculation.  Is that the random value?  Could you **edit the question** and include a listing of the raw data so we can  see what you mean.

Comment: I'm guessing your using it wrong. Checking inside a Arduino library for MPU9250 it seems that you need to read 6 bytes and combine them into a signed 16-bit value to get the real value of the gyro sensor.

Comment: Ok sorry, i was basically half a sleep
 cant include the list at the momment, im at work would check later at night, but the main idea was to gather plain raw data from the Low value of each X, Y and Z elements of the Accelerometer and Gyroscope. 
Honestly i had no idea that it needs to be read into a 16-bit value, if thats the case my problem is parcially on the type declaration, i will also check that.
 also what arduino library do you refer to? im using PIGPIO c++ library for RPi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rate gyros are notorious for being noisy. The major problem I see in your code is that you are reading four high bytes into an array and then reading four low bytes into another array and only then combining them into their int_16 forms.

I think that you should read the two bytes that form the value as a single read so that the value doesn't change in the middle of the read.

There should be a function that reads a block of data from a number of successive registers on the i2c device into an array on the Arduino.

The [SparkFun MPU-9250-DMP Arduino Library](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_MPU-9250-DMP_Arduino_Library/blob/master/src/util/arduino_mpu9250_i2c.cpp) uses a generic function to do this. It works because the bytes are in successive registers.

Using the library above, you might need to read the data like

```
unsigned char byte_data[2];
int int_data;
arduino_i2c_read(MPU_9250_ADDR, GYRO_REGISTER_ADDRESS, NUM_BYTES_INT, byte_data);
int data = byte_data[0] << 8 | byte_data[1];
```

Rather than use "Magic" numbers, I would have defined the constants so that I would be able to understand the code when I looked at it again a month from now.

Rather than averaging four samples, I would use (if I'm remembering correctly, I don't have my code here) a low-pass filter to remove most of the noise.

Another possible choice is a Kalman filter which is good for estimating the correct value but is more computationally expensive.

Happy programming!

Comment: whats better a kalman filter or use quaternion?? the last one i have code i downloaded from git hub but its kinda complicated.

Comment: A Kalman filter is a way of estimating the correct value when you have not-so-correct data. Quaternions are a way of describing 3-dimensional angles to they don't get locked up. A Kalman filter and Quaternions are different sorts of things and can't really be compared to one another.